# List comprehension to evaluate to true if list contains a value

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a long list of values and want a list comprehension to evaluate to True (and print "True" only once if any value in the list is the integer 1).

I can print "True" for each instance a 1 is found but cannot see how to just have it return a single True.

**Code**

```
a = [0,0,1,1,0,1]

b = [print("True") for i in a if i == 1]
print('\n')
#c = [print("True") if any i in a is True] # doesn't work, syntax error



d = [print("TRUE") if any(i == 1)]
```

Comment: btw, You almost never want to have `print()` inside a list comprehension.

Comment: ok, why is that?

Comment: print returns None. So no point storing its output in list.

Comment: Because a list comprehension is a way of transforming one list into another. No printing involved.

Comment: `print('{}'.format(any(a)))` would work, although it would print False if no 1 found.

Comment: I didn't know that, the first comprehension line works but prints 'True' for each instance.

Comment: Why do you need a comprehension at all? `print(1 in a)`?

Comment: @Sayse is right, we sometimes do not think of the easiest idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to convert the resulting list to `bool()`?

```py
a = [0,0,1,1,0,1]
b = bool([i for i in a if i == 1])
print(b)
```

Comment: Thats what I meant quamrana, I will rewrite the question to reflect that in case it helps someone else. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if your list only contains zeros and ones you could just `print(any(a))`
otherwise you could do this

```
a = [0,0,1,0,2,0]
b =[x==1 for x in a]
print(any(b))
```

returns `True`